# Deleted EFI system partition

Tags: boot, grub, boot-loader

Deleted my EFI system partition by accident.  Dual boot system with Linux Mint and Windows, but I wanted to remove windows.  After deleting the windows partition I meant to delete the windows boot manager partition.  However, I accidentally erased the EFI partition.  My bios now does not show any boot options.
I have a live boot USB for Mint that will boot.
Could anybody give instructions on creating another efi partition and having it load grub again?

Comment: Use https://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/ to boot your system. Then install boot-repair.

Comment: Also you can use your live cd. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing try Via chroot way.

Comment: If you deleted partition you need to use gparted to add a FAT32 partition with esp,boot flags to make it a new ESP. You then have to use Boot-Repair's advanced mode to totally reinstall grub or chroot into system to reinstall grub. Make sure fstab gets updated to UUID of new ESP, not with old UUID of deleted partition. Grub install should do that, but best to check.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't overwritten the old EFI partition yet, you could simply boot using SystemRescue and use `testdisk` to recover the partition.

Comment: If testdisk is unable to recover the partition, it isn't too hard to recreate it and repopulate it with boot recovery tools in both linux and windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried to make changes to the disk and if you know the exact size of what the EFI partition was then you can just recreate the partition (don't format it) but after you recreate the partition, run `dosfsck /dev/disk/part<n>` (usually partition #1) or run `fsck.vfat /dev/disk/part<n>` to see if it recognizes the filesystem, I recommend running it in check only mode before attempting to fix it (if repair is even required):

```
fsck.vfat --help
Usage: fsck.vfat [OPTIONS] DEVICE
Check FAT filesystem on DEVICE for errors.

Options:
  -a              automatically repair the filesystem
  -A              toggle Atari variant of the FAT filesystem
  -b              make read-only boot sector check
  -c N            use DOS codepage N to decode short file names (default: 850)
  -d PATH         drop file with name PATH (can be given multiple times)
  -f              salvage unused chains to files
  -F NUM          specify FAT table NUM used for filesystem access
  -l              list path names
  -n              no-op, check non-interactively without changing
  -p              same as -a, for compat with other *fsck
  -r              interactively repair the filesystem (default)
  -S              disallow spaces in the middle of short file names
  -t              test for bad clusters
  -u PATH         try to undelete (non-directory) file that was named PATH (can be
                    given multiple times)
  -U              allow only uppercase characters in volume and boot label
  -v              verbose mode
  -V              perform a verification pass
  --variant=TYPE  handle variant TYPE of the filesystem
  -w              write changes to disk immediately
  -y              same as -a, for compat with other *fsck
  --help          print this message
```

Worst case if you can't restore the partition it is possible to recreate it. For future reference I've never tried this but if you don't know what the exact partition size was, then you might be able to glean some of that information by looking at the volume header (dd the offset from where the start of the partition existed, and look at it in a hex editor, but I have never tried this):

[https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/fs/fat/fat-1.html)

To do it from scratch: reformat / reinstall the GRUB EFI executable, first recreate the partition with `parted`

for example:

```
sudo parted /dev/hda<n> mkpart primary fat32 1 256
```

will give you a partition of 256MB **BUT** you should refer to this to make sure you are creating with the **EXACT** size of the original partition if that's the route you're trying to go:

https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/unit.html

next format it:
`mkfs.vfat -F32 /dev/hda<n>`

if you're needing to do a whole chroot to install your boot loader:

- mount root
  `mount /dev/sda<n> /mnt`
- mount boot
  `mount /dev/sda<n> /mnt/boot`
- mount efi
  `mount /dev/sda<n> /mnt/boot/efi`
- mount dev
   `mount -o rbind /dev/ /mnt/dev`
- mount proc
  `mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc`
- chroot
  `chroot /mnt/ /bin/bash`
- grub-install
  `grub-install` or `update-bootloader` depending on your OS

after that:

- `umount /mnt/boot/efi`
- `umount /mnt/boot`
- `sync ; sync ; mount -o remount,ro /mnt`
- `sync ; sync ; reboot -f`